# Unable to pass multiple arguments to handleChange in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

I am making a checklist using React. Here's my `Parent` component:

```
<ul>
{this.props.data.map(item => {
      return(
      <div><Child {...item} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange("Hello", e)}/></div>);
      })}
</ul>
```

which calls on `Child` component that prints list elements:

```
<li>
   <input
      type="checkbox"
      value={this.props.value}
      onChange={event => this.props.onChange(this.props.id, this.props.value, event.target.checked)}
   />
      {this.props.value}
   </li>
```

and here's the `handleChange` method:

```
handleChange(myString, e) {
    console.log(e.target.id, e.target.value, e.target.checked, myString);
  }
```

I want to pass a custom string of my own to `handleChange` method but I am unable to do that. I have seen several posts regarding this topic but I need help correcting what I am doing wrong. The problem seems to be the way I send `onChange` data from `Child` component back to `Parent` component. Above is what I have written so far. I get an error `Cannot read property id of undefined`. I would appreciate some help regarding how to fix this.

Comment: Could you post full code of yout components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling a function that's defined like this in props `onChange` of `Child` in the parent component:

```
(e) => this.handleChange("Hello", e)
```

with a call that's like this in `Child` inside your `onChange` clickhandler on the `input` element:

```
onChange(this.props.id, this.props.value, event.target.checked)
```

that obviously won't work.

Change your `input` element in `Child` to this:

```
<input
      ...
      onChange={this.props.onChange}
   />
```

to just pass the event object through.